# backtesting garch in r

Tags: r, time-series, arima, quantitative-finance

I am trying to backtest my arch model using ugarchroll but I am getting this warning message

"Warning message:
In .rollfdensity(spec = spec, data = data, n.ahead = n.ahead, forecast.length = forecast.length,  :

non-converged estimation windows present...resubsmit object with different solver parameters."

this is my code

```
library(quantmod)
library(rugarch)

getSymbols("SPY")
rets=ROC(SPY$SPY.Close)
tgarch = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                    variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH"),
                    distribution.model = "std")
garchroll<-ugarchroll(tgarch, data = rets,n.start =500, 
                      refit.window="window", refit.every =200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you apply `ROC()`, first entry became `NA`. So, you want to exclude it from your `rets` when you apply `ugarchroll()`. Hence,

```
garchroll <- ugarchroll(tgarch, data=rets[-1, ], n.start=500, 
                        refit.window="window", refit.every=200)
```